# SSIS 2008 R2 can a property expression and variable be used to set the column delimiter in a Flat File Connection Manager

Tags: ssis

I have a package that writes 46 tables to table specific delimited flat files. A single package variable is used in the 46 Connection Managers to set the output folder path in the Connecting Strings, so that if the path changes only the single variable needs to change. I would link to use a variable in these Connection Managers to set the Column Delimiter.

Comment: Take a look at the expressions in your 46 connection managers. Can you find the delimiter property? Set it.

Comment: Nick thanks. No there is not one by default. I was hoping there was some way of adding or exposing it. John

Comment: That's not too much of a suprise since changing the delimiter (as far as SSIS is concerned) completely changes the metadata. You might need to implement a prior process that changes the existing delimiter to a consistrnt one for SSIS to use.